# Copy an INSERT entity from one dxf file to another dxf file using ezdxf?

Tags: python, autocad, cad, autocad-plugin

I have a dxf file `blocks.dxf` containing multiple block entities.
I have another dxf file `in.dxf` into which I need to import the block entities of the previous dxf file `blocks.dxf`.

How do I copy the block entities from one file to another using `ezdxf` Python module so that the copied blocks can be inserted anywhere in the `in.dxf` file?

Answer (score 0):

For people still looking for an answer on how to copy block definitions:

```
    #generate list of blocks to import
    list_of_blocks = df_uni_temp[mask].RefNo2.tolist()

    doc_blocks = ezdxf.readfile('blocks.dxf')
    doc = ezdxf.readfile('in.dxf')
    importer = Importer(doc_blocks, doc)
    #iterate through list of blocks
    for b in list_of_blocks :
        print(b)
        importer.import_block(b)
    importer.finalize()
```